# What would be the best way of converting Object ArrayList to Double List

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I've started to learn Java/Android and I am trying to gather RSSI values of bluetooth devices. I have 2 fragments on the same activity and every device I discover I show on a listview and keep collecting the data in a ArrayList which holds my object class. later when I want to visualize the data for a device, I need to convert this object array list to ArrayList to get only RSSI values and show on the second fragment. My Problem is this conversion made my screens very slow. Any suggestions? Thank you

This is the function , I think it makes it slow;

```
public static ArrayList<Double> extractDeviceRSSIOnly(ObjDevice device,
        ArrayList<ObjDevice> list)
{
    ArrayList<Double> selectedList=new ArrayList<Double>();
    if(device!=null&& list!=null) {
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                if(list.get(i).get_macAddress().equals(device.get_macAddress())) {
                    selectedList.add(list.get(i).get_signalStrength());
                }
            }
        }
        return selectedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume `get_macAddress()` is just a simple function that returns a stored property, or is there actual logic in place that requires crunching?  Also, how long is your list?  Beyond those two things, your code seems fine to me.

Comment: It is just returning a string property there is no complex calculation behind.Other thing is that, list size can be 100 up to 1000's.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. You can make it a tiny bit more efficient by avoiding calling `get(i)` twice. The [enhanced for](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) will help you with that, and will give you a cleaner code.

As suggested by @Makoto, you can avoid the `list.size() > 0` test too. An empty list will simply not iterate.

```
if (device != null && list != null) {
    for (ObjDevice objDevice : list) {
        if (objDevice.get_macAddress().equals(device.get_macAddress())) {
            selectedList.add(objDevice.get_signalStrength());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even get rid of the size check on `list`.  If it's empty it just won't iterate.

Comment: Would it really matter though? Aren't ArrayLists constant time access?

Comment: It will only matter as it won't be inspecting the address of the `i`th element twice.

Comment: When I remove list.size()>0 and used enhanced for loop, it became much faster.